# ParallelSaveError: Cannot save() the same doc multiple times in parallel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am getting this error for a while now. I think that a promise would solve the problem of this error. Here is my code without the promise function. Is there any way I can solve it without returning a promise?

```
Tag.find({ tag: bmTweet.tag }, function (err, tag) {
    if (tag.length === 0) {
        bmtTag.tag = bmTweet.tag
        Tag.create(bmtTag, function (err, tag) {
            user[0].tags.push(tag)
            user[0].save()
            console.log('Tag created.')
        })
    }
})
Tweet.create(bmTweet, function (err, tweet) {
    user[0].tweets.push(tweet)
    user[0].save()
    console.log('Tweet saved.')
})
```

Here is my code with the promise function:

```
Tag.find({ tag: bmTweet.tag }, function (err, tag) {
    if (tag.length === 0) {
        bmtTag.tag = bmTweet.tag
        Tag.create(bmtTag, function (err, tag) {
            user[0].tags.push(tag)
            user[0].save()
            console.log('Tag created.')
            return Promise.resolve({ msg: 'Worked' })
        }).then(function () {
            Tweet.create(bmTweet, function (err, tweet) {
                user[0].tweets.push(tweet)
                user[0].save()
                console.log('Tweet saved.')
            })
        })
    }
})
```

I am new to this. So please help me identify my rookie error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was actually doing it the wrong way. I figured, that the second function needs to be called anyway, why not do it the other way round. So, I returned a promise form `Tweet.create` and added a `.then` to `Tag.create`. Here is the updated code:

```
func.tweetCreate(bmTweet, user)
  .then(function (msg) {
            func.tagFindOrCreate(bmTweet, bmtTag, user);
  });
```

And the function definition:

```
tweetCreate: function (tweet, user) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        Tweet.create(tweet, function (err, tweet) {
            user[0].tweets.push(tweet);
            user[0].save();
            console.log("Tweet saved.")
            resolve();
        })
    })
}
```